# 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: django, python-3.6

Error in the line as below: 
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'pk'

```
 friend_user = User.objects.get(pk=Friend.to_user.id)
```

Thanking you in advance,

models.py

```
 class Friend(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="to_user")
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.to_user.email
```

Comment: show your models will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'id' instead of 'pk', If Friend is your another model, then need to get an instance of Friend class. So that you can access the attributes

```
friend_user = User.objects.get(id=Friend.to_user.id)
```

Comment: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

The `related_name` specifies the name of the relation at the target model, so your

```py
to_user = models.ForeignKey(
   AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
   related_name="to_user"  # <-- confusing relation name
)
```

adds a relation `User.to_user`. This is a confusing name because this `to_user` actually relates to a `Friend`. And because a foreign key technically allows multiple friends refer to the same user, it should be a plural.

So a better name would be `to_friends`, which adds `Friend.to_user` and  `User.to_friends`:

```py
to_user = models.ForeignKey(
    AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="to_friends"  # <-- better relation name
)
```

Provided you changed the name of the relation, you can find the friend for a given user using:

```py
friend = User.to_friends.get(id=...)
```

assuming the user actually has this friend. If not, you get a `Friend.DoesNotExist` exception. If you want to avoid that and get a `None` friend instead, use:

```py
friend = User.to_friends.filter(id=...).first()
if friend is not None:
   ... # Do something with friend.
```